# OCR for US census 1930

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, ocr

The US census for 1930 is available online as a series of large pdfs.  Sadly, as far as I can see, there is no free service that has also run OCR on it.  There are, on the other hand, a lot of online examples of successful OCR done by "enthusiastic amateurs".  So, let's start  at the beginning.

For example, a single page can be seen at http://i47.tinypic.com/2i7tt8k.png, and here is another one:

[image]

What would be a good way to extract the different words from the image so that one can start to try to train a system to recognise them?   Ultimately I am seeing this as a tricky machine learning problem.

You can download the entire image files from http://archive.org/details/newyorkcensus00reel1475 and associated links.

Comment: It looks like you already pre-processed that other page, right ?